# Javascript import and using paths

Tags: javascript, import, path

I am trying to import some files in JS, but i am confused as to how the paths work.

Looking this code snippet from here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html

```
import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';
import Stats from './jsm/libs/stats.module.js';
import { STLLoader } from './jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js';
```

What is the difference between `../` and `./` ?

If the HTML file is in the same directory with another file, then can i use a direct reference to the other file such as `loader.load( 'model.stl');` or do i have to use the dot reference?

Answer (score 0):

`./` means the target file is in the same directory as your current file
`../` means the target file is one directory up from the current file

If you don't use the dot notation you need to provide an absolute path to your file from your project's root

Answer (score 0):

Import paths are relative to the file *importing* them. `.` is an alias for *this directory* – same directory as this file. `..` is an alias for *parent directory*.

As of your example, the directory structure would be..

```
master
 |-build
 |  |-three.module.js
 |-example
    |-jsm
    |  |-libs
    |  |  |-stats.module.js
    |  |-loaders
    |     |-STLLoader.js
    |-webgl_loader_stl.html
```